# Detecting Filename Patterns for Creating RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

When using a string to define a RegEx, I'd like to know if there is a way to get my code to recognize a pattern in the files contained within a directory.

The goal is to rename these files using our naming conventions, so I'm writing something to try to create the expression to use in RegEx.

I've started something here, but I don't think it is the best, and I'm not sure how to fill in the `"{0}"` portion of my RegEx expression.

```
    private Regex m_regex;

    public string DirPattern(string path, string[] extensions) {
        string result = null;
        int endPos = 0;
        int resLen = 0;
        int startLen = 0;
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles()) {
            if (extensions.Contains(file.Extension)) {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) {
                    int sL = 0;
                    int fileLen = file.Name.Length;
                    string one = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < resLen && i < fileLen; i++) {
                        if (result[i] == file.Name[i]) {
                            sL = i + 1;
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(one)) {
                                one = file.Name;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(one)) {
                        int eP = 0;
                        int oneLen = one.Length;
                        for (int i = fileLen - 1; -1 < i; i--) {
                            if (result[i] == file.Name[i]) {
                                eP = i - 1;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if ((0 < endPos) && (eP == endPos)) {
                            if ((0 < startLen) && (sL == startLen)) {
                                result = one.Substring(0, startLen) + "{0}" + one.Substring(endPos);
                            } else if (0 < sL) {
                                startLen = sL;
                            }
                        } else if (0 < sL) {
                            startLen = sL;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    result = file.Name;
                    resLen = result.Length;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool GenerateRexEx(string path, string[] extensions) {
        var pattern = DirPattern(path, extensions);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern)) {
            m_regex = new Regex(pattern);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is an example of a list of files that would be most like our company files (which I am not allowed to post):

[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE:**

The goal is to take files with names like this:

```
FOLDER_PATTERN_1 + MixedContent + FOLDER_PATTERN_2
```

and rename them using our format:

```
OUR_PATTERN_1 + MixedContent + OUR_PATTERN_2
```

That way, our software will be able to search the files more efficiently.

Comment: Based on the Folder name how come you can't come up with a string.Formatted naming convention are you trying to do pattern sequence along with determine what the last 2 digit value is within the file name.. I can see several ways to write something especially using the string.Split along with string.Format and string.Join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case you need just to find count of characters in the prefix pattern and postfix pattern. Then you can simply replace some count of characters with your pattern. I wrote a simple code which I tested and works. You can inspire yourself and use the same method I think. Anyway there are areas to make this better, but I hope it is enough to answer your question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var inputFilenames = new string[]
            {
                "mtn_flint501-muxed",
                "mtn_flint502-muxed",
                "mtn_flint503-muxed",
                "mtn_flint504-muxed",
                "mtn_flint505-muxed",
                "mtn_flint506-muxed",
                "mtn_flint507-muxed",
                "mtn_flint508-muxed",
                "mtn_flint509-muxed",
                "mtn_flint510-muxed",
                "mtn_flint511-muxed",
                "mtn_flint512-muxed",
            };
            var replacedFilenames = ReplaceFileNames(inputFilenames);

            for (int i = 0; i < inputFilenames.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} >> {1}", inputFilenames[i], replacedFilenames[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private const string OurPrefixPattern = "Prefix_";
        private const string OurPostfixPattern = "_Postfix";

        /// <summary>
        /// Method which will find the filename's pattern and replace it with our pattern
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileNames"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string[] ReplaceFileNames(params string[] fileNames)
        {
            //At first, we will find count of characters, which are same for
            //all filenames as prefix and store it to prefixCount variable and
            //we will find count of characters which are same for all filenames
            //as postfix and store it to postfixCount variable
            var prefixCount = int.MaxValue;
            var postfixCount = int.MaxValue;
            //We will use first filename as the reference one (we will be comparing)
            //all filenames with this one
            var referenceFilename = fileNames[0];
            var reversedReferenceFilename = referenceFilename.ReverseString();
            //Lets find the prefixCount and postfixCount
            foreach (var filename in fileNames)
            {
                if (filename == referenceFilename)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //Check for prefix count
                var firstDifferenceIndex = referenceFilename.GetFirstDifferentIndexWith(filename);
                if (firstDifferenceIndex < prefixCount)
                {
                    prefixCount = firstDifferenceIndex;
                }
                //For postfix count we will do the same, but with reversed strings
                firstDifferenceIndex = reversedReferenceFilename.GetFirstDifferentIndexWith(filename.ReverseString());
                if (firstDifferenceIndex < postfixCount)
                {
                    postfixCount = firstDifferenceIndex;
                }
            }
            //So now replace given filnames with our prefix and post fix.
            //Our regex determines only how many characters should be replaced
            var prefixRegexToReplace = string.Format("^.{{{0}}}", prefixCount);
            var postfixRegexToReplace = string.Format(".{{{0}}}$", postfixCount);
            var result = new string[fileNames.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                //Replace the prefix
                result[i] = Regex.Replace(fileNames[i], prefixRegexToReplace, OurPrefixPattern);
                //Replace the postfix
                result[i] = Regex.Replace(result[i], postfixRegexToReplace, OurPostfixPattern);
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the first index in which the strings has different character
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="stringToCompare"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static int GetFirstDifferentIndexWith(this string value, string stringToCompare)
        {
            return value.Zip(stringToCompare, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2).TakeWhile(b => b).Count();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Revers given string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">String which should be reversed</param>
        /// <returns>Reversed string</returns>
        private static string ReverseString(this string value)
        {
            char[] charArray = value.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
    }
}
```

The console output looks like this

> mtn_flint501-muxed >> Prefix_01_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint502-muxed >> Prefix_02_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint503-muxed >> Prefix_03_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint504-muxed >> Prefix_04_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint505-muxed >> Prefix_05_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint506-muxed >> Prefix_06_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint507-muxed >> Prefix_07_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint508-muxed >> Prefix_08_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint509-muxed >> Prefix_09_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint510-muxed >> Prefix_10_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint511-muxed >> Prefix_11_Postfix
>
> mtn_flint512-muxed >> Prefix_12_Postfix